# Flash slideshow in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash

Never had to do some ...Flash stuff, but now a customer wants me to make a Flash intro in her (ASP MVC) site!

The scenario is this: images are stored in the dbms. Every image belongs to a category. Depending on what category is selected, the corresponding images should be fetched and played in a flash player with "transition" effects (hope i used the correct words).

How can a slideshow (swf) be created dynamically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I used to roll my own for these sorts of things, but now I like to use slideshowpro. (It costs something like $25 bucks for a single site license.) I think you can set it up without the Flash IDE, since there's an API, but it's a bit easier with the IDE, since there are a lot of options. It takes an xml feed which is pretty easy to generate as the input. http://slideshowpro.net/

(Note: there are other similar solutions out there. I settled on SSP as the most extensible a few years ago. Haven't done a comparison recently.)